# Highcharts categories adjust yAxis.labels.y to bottom of lane

Tags: highcharts

Using Highcharts and categories on the yAxis, how can I make the category label display near the bottom of the category/lane rather than the middle? Looking for something like `verticalAlign: 'bottom'`.

Similar to [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-x/) I tried adjusting the `yAxis.labels.y` value (which does cause it to move) but because the tick & label begin in the middle of the category/lane when using categories, the offset to be adjusted is not known due to a variable chart size and number of categories.

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    align: 'left',
    x: 0,
    y: -2
  }
}
```

[Here is a slightly modified version](http://jsfiddle.net/wphampton/ar755a3n/) of the above example that uses categories on the yAxis but does not currently sit at the correct location if you add/remove categories. Wondering if a better idea might be to hide the yAxis labels altogether and handle the swimlanes and labels with plotbands instead.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `yAxis.labels.y` offset but set [yAxis.tickmarkPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickmarkPlacement) to `'on'`. It will affect only a categorized axis but makes the labels to in line with grid lines.

```
    yAxis: {
        categories: ['Category Named A', 'Category Named B', 'Category Named C', 'Category Named D', 'Category Named E', 'Category Named F', 'Category Named G', 'Category Named H'],
    labels: {
        align: 'left',
        x: 0,
        y: -2,
    },
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
},
```

example with categories: http://jsfiddle.net/kcn9tse8/

example w/o categories: http://jsfiddle.net/kcn9tse8/1/

Comment: Thank you -- it's not a bad solution at all -- but it does cause the individual markers to no longer be in the center of the lane. I was hoping to only adjust the label location to prevent markers from displaying on top of the label as they do in the first data point in above examples. I'll leave this open just a bit longer to see if anything else gets stirred up. Thanks again!